# DHCP, DNS, DC on single VM

Tags: domain-name-system, hyper-v, dhcp-server

I'm trying to install simple scheme of server:

Hype-V as host
DNS, DHCP, DC on single VM.

However I've got difficulties with make my DHCP server work - client devices got IPs only from my MikroTik router (when DHCP is turned on router) or are getting none (when DHCP is turned off on router). Only when I manually change IP settings on the client device to match my server, it reaches the domain controller, but there is no internet connection.

There is scheme I'm trying to apply:

[Network scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCMZc.png)

What I'm also not sure about and would like to hear you suggestions as well, is setting of virtual network adapter - on HyperV host site and on the VM. Should there be loopback address, router IP or something else? Should I leave host machine with DHCP enabled?

Comment: What type of Hyper-V virtual switch did you create?

Comment: External, enabling to share this network adapter